# For Each +1 Wordpress Loop

Tags: loop

Im using a loop to make a slider. My code is

```
<?php 
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'my_gallery', 'author'=>$author->ID ) );

while( have_posts() ) : 
    the_post(); 
    $imagethum = eh_postImage(115, 70); 
?>
<a data-slide-index="0" href=""><?php echo $imagethum; ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I need the `data-slide-index="0"` attribute to increase by 1 for every post in the loop so the output appears as...

```
<a data-slide-index="0" href="">
<a data-slide-index="1" href="">
<a data-slide-index="2" href="">
<a data-slide-index="3" href="">
<a data-slide-index="4" href="">
<a data-slide-index="5" href="">
```

after printed

Some kind of `for each` statement here?

Comment: also I strongly recommend against using `query_posts`, it is never a good idea, instead WP_Query objects, the pre_get_posts filter or the get_posts function are your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try yo use the build-in loop counter:

```
  <a data-slide-index="<?php echo $wp_query->current_post; ?>" href=""><?php echo $imagethum; ?></a>
```